# combine two nested for loops in one for loop in julia

Tags: for-loop, julia

I have two for loops and I want to combine them as one nested loop:

my loops are like this:

```
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        .....
    end
end
```

I tried to combine them :

```
for ii = 1:n*m
    ai = ii%n 
    yi = ii % m
    if(ai == 0)
        ai=6
    end
    if(yi == 0)
        yi=5
    end
    println("ai=$ai , yi=$yi")
end
```

so that I got this result:

```
ai=1 , yi=1
ai=2 , yi=2
ai=3 , yi=3
ai=4 , yi=4
ai=5 , yi=5
ai=6 , yi=1
ai=1 , yi=2
ai=2 , yi=3
ai=3 , yi=4
ai=4 , yi=5
ai=5 , yi=1
ai=6 , yi=2
ai=1 , yi=3
ai=2 , yi=4
ai=3 , yi=5
ai=4 , yi=1
ai=5 , yi=2
ai=6 , yi=3
ai=1 , yi=4
ai=2 , yi=5
ai=3 , yi=1
ai=4 , yi=2
ai=5 , yi=3
ai=6 , yi=4
ai=1 , yi=5
ai=2 , yi=1
ai=3 , yi=2
ai=4 , yi=3
ai=5 , yi=4
ai=6 , yi=5
```

but I want to get some result like this:

```
ai=1 , yi=1
ai=1 , yi=2
ai=1 , yi=3
ai=1 , yi=4
ai=1 , yi=5
ai=2 , yi=1
ai=2 , yi=2
ai=2 , yi=3
ai=2 , yi=4
ai=2 , yi=5
ai=3 , yi=1
ai=3 , yi=2
ai=3 , yi=3
ai=3 , yi=4
ai=3 , yi=5
ai=4 , yi=1
ai=4 , yi=2
ai=4 , yi=3
ai=4 , yi=4
ai=4 , yi=5
ai=5 , yi=1
ai=5 , yi=2
ai=5 , yi=3
ai=5 , yi=4
ai=5 , yi=5
ai=6 , yi=1
ai=6 , yi=2
ai=6 , yi=3
ai=6 , yi=4
ai=6 , yi=5
```

I don't know how can I change my code to get some nested result. It is possible to combine two for loops to one for loops so that they are running same as two loops are running?

Comment: but why? converting linear indices to Cartesian subscripts is costly than the other way around(`div` is slower than `*`&`+`). [here](https://julialang.org/blog/2016/02/iteration) is a great post to learn how to do iteration with `CartesianIndex` in Julia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit:**

Julia has nice mathematical functions and **divrem** is the right answer! :)

```
 for ii = 1:n*m
     ai, yi = divrem(ii-1, n) .+ (1,1)      
     print(ai,",", yi, "  ")
 end
# Output: 1,1  1,2  1,3  1,4  2,1  2,2  2,3  2,4  3,1  3,2  3,3  3,4
```

**old answer:**

If this is question about Julia then how not to do it. :)

```
m=3;n=4;

for ii = 1:m*n
    ai = div(ii-1, n) + 1  # division here
    yi = (ii-1)%n + 1      # modulo here
    print(ai,",", yi,"  ")
end

# Output: 1,1  1,2  1,3  1,4  2,1  2,2  2,3  2,4  3,1  3,2  3,3  3,4
```

But you need to see that performance and readability is **much worse** than with this code:

```
for ai in 1:3
    for yi in 1:4 
        print(ai,",", yi,"; ")
    end
end
```

Comment: that's terrible! :-D

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard I agree! :-D But I think it is what OP wanted. And maybe with thousands CUDA procs it could help him to create faster code?

Comment: @ReD if you do `for i in 1:m for j in 1:n` you do approximately m*n addition which is faster instruction than divrem (and you still need also to do m*n additions  with `for i in 1:m*n`. But if you have m*n processors then it is probably usable because you could do divrem parallel. But it all depends on architecture you are using for computing!

Answer (score 17):

Yes.

```
for i=1:m, j=1:n
    .....
end
```

Comment: I know that but I wanted something like `for ii=1:m*n`

Comment: Why? --15 chars

Comment: No, It's because I want to run it parallel, and I want to have one loop instead of two loops and then run it as parallel

Comment: @Fazeleh If you try this with some simple example with `break`, you'll see that this is one loop instead of two.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Iterators.product`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/iterators/#Base.Iterators.product) for this if your actual use requires just one iterable:

```
julia> for (i,j) in Iterators.product(1:4, 1:3)
           println("i=$i , j=$j")
       end
i=1 , j=1
i=2 , j=1
i=3 , j=1
i=4 , j=1
i=1 , j=2
i=2 , j=2
i=3 , j=2
i=4 , j=2
i=1 , j=3
i=2 , j=3
i=3 , j=3
i=4 , j=3
```

Comment: Is there any different between the running time? Dose it improve the running time?

Comment: Why not? --15 chars

Comment: @ReD probably wants to calculate ai, yi indices (independently) from position number of processor/process/thread.